# discord.js: Slash command giving unwanted results and crashing the bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have been a working on a discord bot for personal uses. The following code is `sendImage.js` from that project:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder, userMention, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle } = require('discord.js');


module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('sendimage')
        .setDescription('send your image to the dm channel')
        .addAttachmentOption(Option => Option.setName('image').setDescription('your image').setRequired(true))
        //add optional next option for the user to add a description to the image
        .addStringOption(Option => Option.setName('gamename').setDescription('what game is this?').setRequired(true))
        .addStringOption(Option => Option.setName('twitterusername').setDescription('let us know your twitter (optional)').setRequired(false)),

    async execute(interaction) {
        
        const image = interaction.options.getAttachment('image'); //takes the image.
        const game = interaction.options.getString('gamename'); //takes the game description.
        var twittername = "N/A"; //initialize twittername
        if (interaction.options.getString('twitterusername') != null) { //if the user adds a twitter username
            twittername = interaction.options.getString('twitterusername'); //set the twittername to the user input
        }
        await interaction.reply('Image sent, waiting for approval!');
        
        const channel = interaction.client.channels.cache.get('1086283992287957202'); //#sent-images channel
        channel.send({ 
            files: [image],
            //also attach the user information to the image
            content: `User: ${userMention(interaction.user.id)}, game: ${game}, twitter: ${twittername}`, //sends the image to #sent-images channel
            //Add buttons to this message
            components: [
                new ActionRowBuilder()
                    .addComponents(
                        new ButtonBuilder()
                                .setCustomId('approve')
                                .setLabel('Approve')
                                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success),
                            )
                    .addComponents(
                        new ButtonBuilder()
                                .setCustomId('deny')
                                .setLabel('Deny')
                                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger))],
        }); 
    
        
        //when the user presses the button, do this
        interaction.client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
            if (!interaction.isButton()) return;
            //if the button pressed is the approve button
            if (interaction.customId === 'approve') {
                //reply 'Image approved!' to the message
                //send the image to the #approved-images channel
                const approvedchannel = interaction.client.channels.cache.get('1086284008704458862'); //#approved-images channel
                await approvedchannel.send({
                    files: [image],
                    //also attach the user information to the image
                    content: `User: ${userMention(interaction.user.id)}, game: ${game}, twitter: ${twittername}`, //sends the image to #sent-images channel
                });
                await interaction.reply('Image approved!');
                
                
            } else if (interaction.customId === 'deny') {
                //reply 'Image approved!' to the message
                //send the image to the #approved-images channel
                const approvedchannel = interaction.client.channels.cache.get('1086284040715374692'); //#approved-images channel
                await approvedchannel.send({
                    files: [image],
                    //also attach the user information to the image
                    content: `User: ${userMention(interaction.user.id)}, game: ${game}, twitter: ${twittername}`, //sends the image to #sent-images channel
                });
                await interaction.reply('Image denied!');
            }
        });
    },
};
```

To explain `sendImage.js`:

1. sendImage.js creates the slash command `/sendImage [image] [gameName] [twittername (optional)]`

[image]

2. User enters these information in DMs and then receives a reply "Image sent, waiting for approval"
3. On the server side, I have three different text channels, `#sent-images`, `#approved-images` and `#rejected-images`

[image]

4. The image that user has sent will appear in `#sent-images` and in this channel, admins are going to either `approve` or `deny` it.

[image]

5. After the approve/deny process, image will be sent to it's respective channel. **Code works up until here just fine**. But whenever I add **another image** using the slash command  and then try to approve/deny that new image again, my bot crashes with the following result:

> This is the first image that I sent with /sendImage (I approved it so it's in #approved-images)
> [image]

> This is the second image that I sent with /sendImage (I rejected it so it's in #rejected-images)
> But in this case #rejected-images sends the previous image in here as well as with the second image.
> [image]

And when I look at the terminal I see that my bot has infact crashed with the following error text:
[image]

How do I make this slash command to forget the previous use by the same user so it doesn't send the previous message as well as the current message and causing the bot to crash?

Any help, feedback and/or suggestion is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: You're creating a new event listener every time someone executes the command (`interaction.client.on('interactionCreate')` is inside the `execute` method which is a callback function of another `client.on('interactionCreate')`).

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros sorry for the late reply, just had the oppurtunity to look at here...
So in this situation what should I do in order to fix this problem? So far I tried putting that part of the code out of the execute method, didn't seem to work, and then I used 
`channel.send ({
 'first part of the code goes here
}).then(
'after interaction.client.on('interactionCreate') line goes here'
) but that also didn't seem to work. Thanks in advance.`

Or what part of the discord.js documentation I should be looking to find out how to deal with this issue.

Comment: when I put `interaction.client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {})` outside of the execute method, I get a syntax error on `interaction.client` `',' expected.`